# Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation

Tags: sqoop

My VM details:
    Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.5.0
    VM = VM workstation 12 player
    Windows = Windows 10 / 64 bit
    Java = Java 1.8

when I run the "sqoop"command , I'm facing the error below:

```
**Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.**
```

Can you please help to rectify this error?

Comment: it's just a **warning**, To make the warning go away you need to install ACCUMULO.

Comment: My two cents: It's a warning, but if you're not using Accumulo, it's noise that makes the rest of the logs even more verbose.  First answer should be accepted, as it works to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to

```
>>> ACCUMULO_HOME='/var/lib/accumulo'
```

and

```
>>> export ACCUMULO_HOME
```

don't forget to create the directory

```
>>> sudo mkdir /var/lib/accumulo
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable `ACCUMULO_HOME` to `/var/lib/accumulo` and export this variable.
This will resolve this warning.

Comment: if you are setting ACCUMULO_HOME to a path, you should make sure that the path is actually where accumulo lives. Otherwise you are suppressing the warning without actually resolving it!

Comment: Many systems do not use accumulo, so warning is purely noise.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be installing through the Apache Bigtop, you may need to use

```
$ export ACCUMULO_HOME=/usr/bin/sqoop
```

test it out with something like

```
$sqoop help import
```

Answer (score 0):

Late but i hope this workaround could help you. I've had the same problem but i'm using the `cloudera sandbox`.

In my case to solve it i just created an empty directory and set `$ACCUMULO_HOME` env variable as following:

```sh
$ sqoop help
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
...
```

As said, first create the accumulo dir

```sh
$ mkdir /var/lib/accumulo
```

Next create the var

```sh
$ ACCUMULO_HOME='/var/lib/accumulo'
$ export ACCUMULO_HOME
```

That's it

```sh
$ echo $ACCUMULO_HOME
$ sqoop help
usage: sqoop COMMAND [ARGS]

Available commands:
  codegen            Generate code to interact with database records
  create-hive-table  Import a table definition into Hive
  eval               Evaluate a SQL statement and display the results
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following commands:

```
1. sudo mkdir /var/lib/accumulo

2. ACCUMULO_HOME='/var/lib/accumulo'

3. export ACCUMULO_HOME
```

Answer (score -2):

Its just a warning that you could ignore. Sqoop tried to validate the environment and send these warning.
If you are really bothered , You could try with
Set up $ACCUMULO_HOME to some directory which you would not use it.