# Python redirect Sqoop execution output on Jupyter

Tags: python, shell, output, jupyter, sqoop

I am trying to execute sqoop command as a shell script from a python, I am executing the code inside Jupyter. I am trying to redirect the output of the execution to the output cell of Jupyter, but I get partial result of the original output that I receive when I execute the script separately in the shell. Below is my code, **May someone advise why I can't see all the logs**:

```
try:  
    print 'Statring the execution of file:' + 'sh', './'+file_name
    print subprocess.check_output(['sh', './'+file_name], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)#, shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print 'Error Occurred'
    print("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd,e.returncode,e.output))
print 'Execution finished'
```

I got the following output:

```
Statring the execution of file:sh ./xxxxxxxxxx_30-jun-2019.sh
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.

Execution finished
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!
Your Error-Message looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440469/warning-usr-lib-sqoop-accumulo-does-not-exist-accumulo-imports-will-fail-p) could maybe help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but actually it doesn't help, as I care why not all logs appear regardless what is inside the logs itself. Besides they are talking about executing the sqoop command in shell script, and I am exeucuting it in the python code.